# How to check whether PHP CLI module is installed or not in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` and I've installed LAMP in my computer. How can I check whether the **CLI** module for php is already installed or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running `php --version` on the commandline. If it works, it's installed.

Comment: @Kenney It works... thanks... yeehaaa... CLI is installed in my system... :)

Answer (score -1):

If you meant verifying that in program...

```
public function isPhpCLIAvailable()
{
    if (exec('php -r \'echo "test";\'') === 'test') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

note that this assumes that "exec" function is allowed.